# How to format macros in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I have the following:

```
EXEC_DATE1 = '{{ macros.ds_add(ds, 1) }}'


EXEC_DATE2 = '{{ execution_date }}'
```

I want to create path variable that looks like:

```
path1 = EXEC_DATE1 + '/' + HH:MM (of EXEC_DATE1)
path2 = EXEC_DATE2 + '/' + HH:MM (of EXEC_DATE2)
```

Eventually it should be like:

```
2018-09-16/10:41
```

How can I do that?

I tried:

```
EXEC_DATE = '{{ execution_date }}'
EXEC_DATE = EXEC_DATE.strftime('%Y-%m-%d/%H:%M')
```

but it gives:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

**EDIT:**
My code:

```
EXEC_TIMESTAMP_PATH = "{{  execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d/%H:%M') }}"
EXEC_DATE = "{{  execution_date.strftime('%H:%M') }}"
EXEC_TIME = "{{  mexecution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}"

task3_op= BashOperator(
    task_id='task3',
    params={'EXEC_DATE':EXEC_DATE, 'EXEC_TIME':EXEC_TIME},
    bash_command="""python3 script.py '{{ var.value.task3_variable }}' '{{ params.EXEC_DATE }}' '{{ params.EXEC_TIME }}' 'file.json'""",
    dag=dag)
```

This doesn't work. The parameters are not rendered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do it as follows:

```
EXEC_DATE = "{{ execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d/%H:%M') }}"
```

The `strftime` should be used inside the curly braces.

If you need next_execution date, use the following:

```
EXEC_DATE = "{{ next_execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d/%H:%M') }}"
```

And if you just want to add a `timedelta`:

```
EXEC_DATE = "{{ (execution_date + macros.timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d/%H:%M') }}"
```

You code can be as follows:

```py
BASH_COMMAND="""
python3 script.py {{ var.value.task3_variable }} {{  execution_date.strftime('%H:%M') }} {{  execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }} file.json
"""

task3_op= BashOperator(
    task_id='task3',
    bash_command=BASH_COMMAND,
    dag=dag)
```

Comment: It's not rendered for my bashoperator

Answer (score 2):

Specifically what's not working in your question's code is that your `params` don't have templating (macro expansion) run on them, but your `bash_command` does. So I'm betting the rendered template view of the `bash_command` is like E.G.:

```
python3 script.py 'task3_variable's value' '{{  execution_date.strftime('%H:%M') }}' '{{  execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}' 'file.json'
```

That is not getting expanded any further, and the `'` are probably throwing the meaning off for Bash too, because effectively you have:

```
params = { 'EXEC_DATE': "{{  execution_date.strftime('%H:%M') }}",
           'EXEC_TIME': "{{  execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}" }
```

So removing one level of macro expansion by directly using the templates you had set in the `params` in the `bash_command` instead, is working better for you.

```
task3_op = BashOperator(
    task_id='task3',
    bash_command="""
python3 script.py '{{ var.value.task3_variable }}' \
'{{execution_date.strftime('%H:%M')}}' '{{execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}}' file.json
    """,
    dag=dag)
```

You should use the [airflow render command](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#render) or check the rendered view in the task instance details of the UI when debugging issues like this.

It would likely show you what's going wrong with your assumed macro expansions.
This example should render to something like:

```
python3 script.py 'task3_variable's value' \
'12:21' '2018-09-16' file.json
```

You were hoping to make two paths based on dates; try:

```
task3_op= BashOperator(
    task_id='task3',
    bash_command="""
python3 script.py \
  '{{ var.value.task3_variable }}' \
  '{{(execution_date + macros.timedelta(days=1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d/%H:%M')}}' \
  '{{execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d/%H:%M')}}' \
  file.json
    """,
    dag=dag)
```

Airflow 1.10 also added `next_execution_date` which might work better for you than adding a day to `execution_date` if your interval is daily.

Answer (score 0):

Incase in your code macros aren't rendering in your custom Airflow Operator, do add this to your custom class function before **init**

template_fields = ('name_of_function_you_passed_macro_in')